# Can a weapon be a holy symbol?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, equipment

So I'm being part of a DnD campaign soon, and I'm making a tempest cleric that worships Thor. Since Thor's weapon is a Warhammmer, and I also use a Warhammer, could the hammer count as a holy symbol or would there need to be some form of engraving/emblem on it for it to count?

Comment: Note: Mjolnir, Thor's hammer, is not a typical warhammer. The handle was made shorter than intended because of Loki's doing (Norse mythology).

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Leaving aside the RPG mechanics, this is what a genuine Holy Symbol of Thor from real life looked like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mj%C3%B6lnir#/media/File:Mjollnir.png It's a very stylized design, and I don't think it would be suitable to use as a weapon.

Comment: Engrave it with "Whosoever holds this hammer, if they be worthy, shall possess the power of Roth" and you'll have everybody looking for a rock singer named Dave. :-)

Answer (score 15):

You can make it work with a common magical item. The Ruby of the War Mage (from Xanathar's Guide to Everything) can be attached to a weapon or shield and allows that item to be used as a spellcasting focus. As mentioned, it has a rarity level of common so it shouldn't be hard to obtain.

Answer (score 11):

## A holy symbol is a defined item and does not have weapon as an option as written

Holy symbols are defined on page 151 of the *Player's Handbook*:

> [A holy symbol] might be an amulet depicting a symbol representing a deity, the same symbol carefully engraved or inlaid as an emblem on a shield, or a tiny box holding a fragment of a sacred relic. [...] A cleric or paladin can use a holy symbol as a spellcasting focus, as described in chapter 10. To use the symbol in this way, the caster must hold it in hand, wear it visibly, or bear it on a shield.

It being a weapon, or engraved on a weapon, are not options per that description. You can on the other hand bear it on your shield. You should ask your DM however about having it on the weapon instead. Unless you're doing it to alleviate action economy somehow, this change shouldn't have any impact (beyond the flavour you're going for) and is likely to be allowed.

Comment: A rust monster will be extra deadly. If you are trying to gain an advantage (vs just getting RP flavor), your DM may use it against you.

Comment: That's a list of things a holy item might be, not a list of things holy items are restricted to. Those are suggested possibilities, not defined options.

Comment: Indeed, the text explicitly says "might be", not absolute "must be" or even ambiguous "can be".

Comment: @user2357112 & WakiNadiVellir normally, yes you'd be right, but that interpretation is contradicted in the following sentence which says to use a holy symbol as a spellcasting focus it *must be* used on one of those three ways. This strongly indicates that the writers most likely didn't realize the nuance of "might" in the previous sentence. Or, they misspoke in saying "must", meaning "if you have x, y, or z holy symbol, you must use x, y, or z this way" and another holy symbol (not mentioned) can be used another way. So... it's not particularly clear...

Comment: A holy symbol might be placed anywhere, but to be used as a spellcasting focus, it "must be" in hand, worn or on a shield.

Comment: @TylerH I disagree that the second sentence restricts the holy symbol to the three listed options.  It says "the caster must hold it in hand, wear it visibly, or bear it on a shield."  It seems to me, if the holy symbol is a weapon and the weapon is being held in hand (most weapons are,) then the criteria of the second sentence are met.  You wouldn't be able to use an arrow maybe, but a standard melee weapon, like OP's warhammer example, should be fine.

Comment: 1) Take a shield with the holy symbol - 2) hammer it into a mace, taking care to reapply the symbol if anything dings it up along the way - 3) checkmate athiests

Answer (score 9):

### Yes.

A holy symbol is given no hard definition in its description, but PHB151 makes a few suggestions and refers the reader to Appendix B for the holy symbols of common gods. Some of these gods (Ares and Tyr are two) have their listed holy symbol as a weapon.

Be warned that your GM may decide to disallow a cleric of Thor to use a warhammer as their holy symbol. If it's not in the book, the GM can veto it, and your GM may decide that the warhammer is not Thor's holy symbol, but rather his favored weapon, a separate concept from older editions of D&D that gave clerics special privileges for using his deity's favored weapon, but has been removed (minus a vestige or two) from 5e.

Be also warned that your GM may be using a setting where Thor is unknown or nonexistent, and when you're playing a holy man you should always work closely with your GM to straighten out which deities are being used and the dogma of their followers.

Comment: It is worth mentioning, however, that a warhammer is typically large enough that a holy symbol could be **inscribed** on its surface (similar to the example of a shield), and that the warhammer's use is such that such an inscription is unlikely to affect the effectiveness of the warhammer as a weapon. So even if the warhammer itself cannot be the holy symbol, the need for a holy symbol could still be satisfied by the warhammer, as opposed to some other object.

Comment: If it's in the book the GM can still veto it, but it might be more likely to lead to upset players.